# Python - How to create a list of floats when their sizes randomized within a specific range and their sum is predetermined

Tags: python, random, sum, size

As written in the title I am interested in a simple way to produce a list of floats in length 'N, whose value ranges from ***0.1 to 0.25*** but whose sum will be fixed and predefined

Example a:

N = 9, sum = 1.575, list = (0.11, 0.24, 0.225, 0.16, 0.169, 0.233, 0.102, 0.2, 0.136)

Example B:

N = 2, Sum = 0.35, list = (0.2, 0.15)

Thanks!

Comment: Could you use the [Dirichlet distribution](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.dirichlet.html) ?

Comment: Hi thanks for your response.

I can use dirichlet, but I do not know how to place the variables in a way that will create the list I want.

Can you help with that?

Thanks

Comment: I have posted sample Python code. Please let me know whether that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One is tempted to use the [Dirichlet distribution](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.dirichlet.html), which returns a vector of *rank* positive real numbers less than 1, whose sum is constrained to be equal to 1.

However, there is a problem: even a linearly scaled Dirichlet distribution{x<sub>i</sub>} --> {a*x<sub>i</sub> + b} has only 2 free parameters. Our problem has 3: xMin = 0.1, xMax = 0.25, xSum = 1.575, to take the values from your first example. So we have no obvious way to implement the x<sub>i</sub> <= xMax constraint directly.

A legal unit Dirichlet variate of rank 9 could consist of a single 1.0  value followed by 8 zero values. A legal scaled Dirichlet variate could consist of a single value of 0.775, followed by 8 values of 0.1, giving the required sum value. So we have sort of a “winner take all” possibility.

But we can always implement the xMax constraint thru plain rejection. Depending on the exact parameters, rejection can get expensive, but at least we are on a sound statistical basis.

We just compute scaled Dirichlet variates until we get one that respects the x<sub>i</sub> <= xMax constraint. We return that one to the caller.

This can be implemented by the following Python code:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as nprd

def getRandList(rng, rank, xMin, xMax, xSum):
    delta = xSum - rank*xMin
    allowedMaxShare = (xMax-xMin) / delta
    #### print("allowedMaxShare = %f" % allowedMaxShare)
    alphas = rank * [1.0]  #  uniform list
    rejectionCount = 0
    maxShare = 2.0  #  certainly above allowedMaxShare
    while (maxShare > allowedMaxShare):
        rejectionCount += 1
        v1 = rng.dirichlet(alphas)
        maxShare = max(v1)

    #### print("rejectionCount = %d" % rejectionCount)
    # scale the successful vector:
    v2 = list (map(lambda r: xMin + r*delta, v1))
    return v2
```

**Trial run:**

```
$ python3
Python 3.9.6 (default, Jul 16 2021, 00:00:00) 
>>> 
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import numpy.random as nprd
>>> from soq import getRandList
>>>
>>> rank=9
>>> xMin=0.1
>>> xMax=0.25
>>> xSum=1.575
>>> randomSeed=42
>>> g0 = nprd.default_rng(randomSeed)
>>> 
>>> v = getRandList(rg0, rank, xMin, xMax, xSum)
>>> 
>>> v
[0.14802819801539244, 0.12496501874018585, 0.19078664992587546, 0.18722819613343228, 0.22566529897386292, 0.14102174372855228, 0.20502851332070077, 0.24961569590423102, 0.10266068525776693]
>>> 
>>> sum(v)
1.575
>>> 
>>> min(v)
0.10266068525776693
>>> 
>>> max(v)
0.24961569590423102
>>>
```

So it looks OK. Let's test it a little bit more:

```
for _ in range(5):
    v = getRandList(rg0, rank, xMin, xMax, xSum)
    #### print("v = %s" % v)
    sv = sum(v) ; mx = max(v) ; mn = min(v)
    print("sum = %f  min=%f  max=%f" % (sv, mn, mx))
```

**Test script output:**

```
sum = 1.575000  min=0.115170  max=0.248764
sum = 1.575000  min=0.113341  max=0.239323
sum = 1.575000  min=0.100097  max=0.228379
sum = 1.575000  min=0.101264  max=0.246103
sum = 1.575000  min=0.107969  max=0.238713
```

So it looks basically correct. The code can still be optimized a bit, while retaining the rejection principle, by having a dedicated generator object. The object could buffer a large number of vector-scaled Dirichlet variates, and host the raw generator together with computed constants such as `allowedMaxShare`.

Comment: Wow(!) thank you very much.

It really helps, I connected it to the existing code and it works great.

Comment: Glad to hear it helps. BTW that's a lot of mostly interpreted Python code. If you can set up a generator object and are conversant with Numpy, you can probably speed up the thing significantly, by vectorizing à la Numpy the unscaled Dirichlet variate generation, the rejection filtering and the final linear scaling step.

Answer (score 0):

try this will provide the list of value ranges from 0.1 to 0.25 whose length is N and sum is as provided

```
 import random
 def num_pieces(num):
    resp_list = []
    while True:
       rnd_num = random.uniform(0.1, 0.25)
       resp_list.append(rnd_num)
       if sum(resp_list) >= num:
          break

    return resp_list

  a = num_pieces(.9)
```

if you want to limit the range use this
`round(random.uniform(1,2), N)`

**updated**

```
import random
def num_pieces(num):
  deci_points = len(str(num).split('.')[1])
  resp_list = []
  while True:
    rnd_num = round(random.uniform(0.1, 0.25),deci_points)
    resp_list.append(rnd_num)
    if sum(resp_list) >= num:
      break

return resp_list
```

Comment: Hey thanks for ur response.

The code does help if I go through the results and correct them manually.

But if I run the code automatically, it turns out that sometimes the sum exceeds the amount I set in advance (1.575), or it turns out that the number of parts in the list is greater than the predetermined N.

Comment: it depends on the floating points of the sum you are passing . i will edit the answer